# Programatically edit a resource table of an external exe?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, portable-executable

> SCENARIO

I'm using **WinAmp** music player which is written in **C/C++**, it comes with some default keyboard shortcuts (accelerator keys) that can be edited for example using a resource editor.

> PROBLEM

I would like to write a very simple Winforms GUI to establish the pause/resume key on the winamp.exe file.

But I miss the basic concept to start trying this, I don't know where to start search for, read, or write the necessary bytes to find, identify, and modify the accelerator table keys.

PS: Winamp.exe has 5 different accelerator tables.

Something like this is What I would like to reproduce:

[image]

...with the capability to edit the desired keys and save changes in the stream.

> QUESTION

Someone could guide me about how I can start modifying the resource for my needs?

I also will agree to use a 3rd party (free) library that could do the hard job for me due to my very basic knowledge about resources.

VirtualKeys translation/representation is not a problem, the problem that I have is locating the resource table(s) to also identify the current VirtualKey codes in my program then edit them and save the changes in the table.

> UPDATE

I've tried the suggested **Vestris ResourceLib** solution but it does not seems to accomplish the task of edit an accelerator key, this is what I've done in VB.Net by following the same example exposed for C# here: https://github.com/dblock/resourcelib/blob/master/Docs/Accelerator.md

```
Imports Vestris.ResourceLib
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Test() Handles MyBase.Shown

        Dim filename As String = "C:\winamp - copy.exe"

        Using rcInfo As New ResourceInfo()

            rcInfo.Load(filename)

            Dim accList As List(Of AcceleratorResource) =
                rcInfo(Kernel32.ResourceTypes.RT_ACCELERATOR).
                ConvertAll(Of AcceleratorResource)(Function(item As Resource) CType(item, AcceleratorResource))

            For Each rc As AcceleratorResource In accList

                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Name: {0}, TypeName: {1}", rc.Name, rc.TypeName))

                For Each acc As Accelerator In rc.Accelerators

                    Console.WriteLine(acc.ToString)

                    If acc.Key = "B"c Then

                        ' Here change the "B" key to an "M", for example.
                        Dim newAcc As New Accelerator
                        ' ...

                    End If

                Next acc

            Next rc

        End Using ' rcInfo

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Try doing a Google search for "Vestris ResourceLib". I'm using a rather old version (1.3), I can see now that it's been updated several times since then.

Comment: Those are just the starting values, the actual values are stored in an INI file after installation.  Trying to hack the EXE will be problematic on the fly because you will be trying to write to a restricted folder.

Comment: @RenniePet Thankyou, I think that the current version is 1.4 (fix me if is wrong), I've seen in the description that this lib can manage the RT_ACCELERATOR resource and I suppose inside are stored the accelerator tables, the problem I see is that this lib comes without any kind of intellisense information, so no documentation, and no official examples about its usage?. EDIT: Ok i've seen examples in github, I will try it, thanks again!

Comment: @Plutonix the hotkeys are built in the WinAmp exe, the developers don't expose those hotkeys for user personalization, what you see in the ini are the hotkeys for the numeric pad. and what you could seee in the WinAmp's UI are the GLOBAL hotkeys to edit, but not the accelerator keys. thanks for comment!

Comment: Sorry, it's been something like three years since I worked with this and I can't remember much about it. As for investigating the structure of the resources there are several tools for this, you can start here: http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/

Comment: @Plutonix I need to check better what you've said because now I'm seeying different hotkey assignations for the same action inside the ini file, maybe I'm wrong with what I've said, I'm gonna try convert those values to vk codes to see. EDIT: I confirm that it does not work changing the key asignation on the ini file.

Comment: thanks both, I would like to point two things: 1) I know the existance of resource editors that could be used by commandline like resHacker, but I would like to learn to develop my own methods without depending on an external tool (but I agree for a 3rd party lib). 2) I successfully hacked the exe RT_ACCELERATOR table using a resource editor and that is the only way that WinAmp can recognize these new key modifications.

Comment: Vestris ResourceLib throws an unknown error when trying to load a file, I've tried the same code that exposes the official examples to load a file: https://github.com/dblock/resourcelib, but it can't load any file by whatever reason :(, no error info

Comment: The problem I've found is `Vestris ResourceLib` can't compile in a portable project then I need to compile for x86, that's not a major problem, but the lib does not seems to support this task, the github page says: `In order to add an accelerator into an executable (.exe or .dll) create a new instance of AcceleratorResource or load an existing one and add instances of Accelerator to its Accelerators collection.` but the truth is that a new instance of Accelerator has only the choice to assign the command,not the key and not the modifiers 'cause the key is ReadOnly,no option to set key at least

Comment: Sorry if I've sent you on a wild goose chase with Vestris ResourceLib. But what you say about being able to create a new Accelerator but you can't specify the key sounds pretty strange. Is there maybe a factory method that provides that service? Or maybe you could open an issue about that at GitHub.

Comment: @RenniePet don't worry at least you helped me to discover an usefull library which could help me in other resource related problems!